# Cant use any git command: acces denied .gitconfig file bad message

Tags: linux, git

I was using my git fine but suddenly when I tried to use `git status` it showed me

```
fatal: unable to access '/home/username/.gitconfig': Bad message
```

I first thought it is because of my git config file is in the venv, but it was OK and, as the error shows, it is because of the `.gitconfig` file in my user directory!

First of all as what I found on the internet I used `git config --global user.name "NewUser"` and `git config --global user.email newuser@example.com`
but it ends in the same error as before.

After I closed and opened my VScode again a Git extension gave me the warning that it cant detect any git exe file on the system and I need to install the Git again!
And when I checked for `git --version` it gave me the same error again!

Literally I cant use any `git` command!

Then I tried to write the configuration by myself and when I opened it in terminal with nano it was nothing in it! and when I wanted to save the changes it gave another error as

```
[ Error writing .gitconfig: Bad message ]
```

Then I looked at the permissions of the file and it was just question mark instead of normal permissions

[image: this is the permission image]

Then I tried to change the permission by `chmod` but it gave the access denied error again!

```
chmod: cannot access '.gitconfig': Bad messag
```

Then I tried to remove it but it cant be removed too!

```
rm: cannot remove '.gitconfig': Bad message
```

I installed and removed git for several time! it did not work either.

I am using manjaro 20.2

Any idea would be appreciated!

**UPDATED**

This is the errors in for dmesg [image: here]
Bunch of these errors here and there

Comment: If using `rm` and `chmod` are giving you `Bad message`, then the problem seems to be not only with git, but on a bigger scale. I am guessing maybe a corrupted hard-drive? Do any other commands work? Can you open other terminals? Did a system restart help?

Comment: Can you try listing the permissions of `.gitconfig` as root? For example, `sudo ls -l ~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: @mnestorov Im not sure about bigger scale problem! cause I dont encounter with any problem with other parts or any command, but recently i had a message about zsh bad history or coruppted history that I fixed it and since then nothing

Comment: @CH. I includded in the post, but i will updated with a picture! for permissions it just shows bunch of ???? ?? ??? ??. nothing more than question mak

Comment: @amirmohammadian Yes, I saw the permissions posted, but do they also show question marks when run as root? It's possible that you don't have permissions to read the permissions of `.gitconfig` for some reason as your current user.

Comment: @amirmohammadian Also, could you try `ls -ld .gitconfig`? It might be possible that for some reason `.gitconfig` has become a directory you don't have execute permissions for.

Comment: @CH. maybe its the case! Im not sure but what can I do more than using sudo! if its the user problem why not any other files and because of not working with chmod I dont know how else I can fix it!

Comment: It smells like a hardware problem

Comment: @CH.about "ls -ld .gitconfig" it shows the same cant acces bad message error!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch really? any advice?

Comment: @amirmohammadian Are you able to access everything else in your home directory without permissions issues?

Comment: Try to run `fsck` ; see [fsck(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fsck.8.html) but be careful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned here, the question marks in the ls output just indicate that it could not stat() the directory entry.
It could be a disk error or possibly filesystem corruption: for an ArchLinux distro, see [`sudo journalctl --since=today` or, form last boot, `sudo journalctl -b -1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120989/7490) to reveal further details.

Check the partition you are in (`df -h .`) and see if this is a [filesystem mounting issue](https://serverfault.com/a/766905/783).

If you see a bunch of messages like:

```
EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p2): ext4_lookup:1574: inode #4833958: comm ls: iget: checksum invalid
```

You should look at your partition from an external session (meaning a [live session from an USB disk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_medium)), as [in here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=244227):

- Rebooted into the live USB
- Mounted a secondary drive.
- `fsck.ext4 -p [my root device]`
- `fsck.ext4 -z [undo file on secondary drive] [my root device]`
- Stepped through all errors and allowed fsck to fix them
- Rebooted into the system and opted to reinstall all packages (see script below)
- Rebooted again ...

The [OP amir-mohammadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12431671/amir-mohammadian) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65420346/cant-use-any-git-command-acces-denied-gitconfig-file-bad-message/65421048#comment115662863_65421048):

> Because I am in my first steps in Linux, I always have a live boot of my distro.
>
> So it was quick, and when I used it "`fsck`" first it said I cant use any `-p` or `-z` because of some errors and I have to do it manually, so I was just typing `y` and `y` and `y`!
> And when I boot again it worked!!

Comment: there isnt any "messages" or "dmesg" in my /var/log/ ! I guess it should be! but its not

Comment: @amirmohammadian `dmesg` is a command, not a file (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html)

Comment: @amirmohammadian manjaro is an ArchLinux distro (https://itsfoss.com/manjaro-vs-arch-linux/), so the commands are different: I have edited my answer.

Comment: thank you so much! I have errors apparently,I will update the post

Comment: @amirmohammadian That looks like a corrupted disk. I have updated my answer to address this.

Comment: @amirmohammadian Well done! What commands did you execute? Did you make the fsck commands from  live USB session?

Comment: yes! because Im in my first steps in Linux I always have a live boot of my distro. so it was quick and when I used it "fsck" first said I cant use any -p or -z because of some errors and I have to do it manualy, so I was just typing y and y and y! and when I boot again it worked!! thank you again

Comment: @amirmohammadian Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visiblility.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

> sudo chown username .gitconfig